# Rust lifetime - Book example solution

Tags: rust, lifetime

On Rust Book there's this lifetime example:

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    x: &'a i32,
}

fn main() {
    let x;                    // -+ x goes into scope
                              //  |
    {                         //  |
        let y = &5;           // ---+ y goes into scope
        let f = Foo { x: y }; // ---+ f goes into scope
        x = &f.x;             //  | | error here
    }                         // ---+ f and y go out of scope
                              //  |
    println!("{}", x);        //  |
}
```

Simplifying this to:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x;
    {
        let y = 42;
        x = &y;
    }

    println!("The value of 'x' is {}.", x);
}
```

Is it possible to have it work without `clone`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You create a value with a short lifetime, then try to maintain a reference to it with a longer lifetime. That simply doesn't work.

Comment: @Aplet123 I'm just trying to understand it. I don't know if there's a way to keep the reference or if in this case it's only possible to have this working by creating a copy.

This causes an error, how can one have the code separated in different scopes like this and have it work?

Comment: You would transfer ownership instead of using references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, you can simply enlarge the lifetime of `y` by removing the scope introduced by the curly braces.

```rust
fn main() {
    let x;

    let y = 42;
    x = &y;

    println!("The value of 'x' is {}.", x);
}
```

Or, as others suggested, you can transfer the ownership from `y` to `x`, i.e. move the value from `y` to `x`, by removing the reference operator `&` from `y`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x;
    {
        let y = 42;
        x = y;
    }

    println!("The value of 'x' is {}.", x);
}
```